# Maven. Exclude some file from uploading to local repository

Tags: maven, aws-lambda, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-install-plugin

I am creating an AWS Lambda package using `maven-assembly-plugin`. It generates several ZIP files in the target directory.

The Maven Plugin `maven-install-plugin` uploads all the JAR and ZIP files located in `target` subdirectory every time I deploy the project. These files are quite heavy. I don't need them in the local repository.

Is the a way to exclude them from uploading to local repository.

Comment: So you don't want any of them in the local repository, or you want to pick some of them?

Comment: Right now I don't need any of them copied to local repository. Picking some of them would be a interesting option as well.

Comment: Then just don't call install but verify.

Comment: @J Fabian. I need deploy phase. Is it possible to call "deploy" skipping "install "?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `<skip>` parameter of the maven install plugin to `true`. You do this in the `<configuration>` section of the plugin definition.